# Why is my 404 handler not working in apache?

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, virtualhost, errordocument

I cannot make my 404 ErrorDocument work

This is my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias landing.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html
        ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html/errors/404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

This are all 304:

```
mydomain.com/errors/404.html
mydomain.com
landing.mydomain.com
```

And this is a 404:

```
http://factuplus.com/noexists.html
```

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /noexists.html was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ErrorDocument` path should be relative to the `DocumentRoot`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias landing.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html
        ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Optionally, you could use the full URL:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias landing.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html
        ErrorDocument 404 http://factuplus.com/errors/404.html
</VirtualHost>
```